# Extract ManyToManyField values

Tags: django

I'm having trouble extracting values from a ManyToManyField in django.  I don't get an error, just an empty queryset.  Here is my code, can you please take a look and let me know if I'm doing something wrong?  I can see the selected values correctly in Admin, which leads me to believe that I have probably stored the values correctly, but I cannot retrieve the values in my views.py.

models.py

```
class Colors(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ColorId = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    ColorName = models.CharField(default='Na', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('ColorName',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ColorName


class Bike(models.Model):
    colors= models.ManyToManyField(Colors)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
class SettingsUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    colors = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Colors.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Bike
    fields = [
              'colors',
              ]
```

a snippet from my html template

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-8 col-md-6">
{{ p_form.colors.label_tag }}
{% render_field p_form.colors class="form-control" %}
</div>
```

I'm able to get other parameters that I have saved by doing something like:

```
bikes= Bike.objects.all()
colors= bikes.colors
```

I suspect that this is where I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

As I mentioned, I'm getting an empty queryset, no errors and I'm able to see the selected values correctly in my Admin panel.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where are you trying to "extract" the values? The only template you've shown here is the form.

Comment: Try this `for bike in bikes:  print(bike.colors)`

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I'm trying to extract the values in my views.py file.

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan, I tried that.  It says  
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Comment: Oh sorry., `for bike in bikes: print(bike.colors.objects.all())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Bike.objects.all()` returns a queryset - a list of all the Bikes. Whatever the type of your field, you can't access that field directly on the queryset; only on the individual models in that queryset. So you will always need to iterate over the contents of `bikes`.

With a many-to-many though, the value of the field is itself a queryset. So you will *also* need to iterate over the colours for each bike. For example:

```
for bike in Bike.objects.all():
    print(bike.name) #  assuming it has a name
    for color in bike.colors.all():
        print(color.ColorName)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'll give that a try.  Ultimately, I am looking to see which options a user has picked.  In this example, if my list of colors is black, red, blue, white, green, etc. and the user only wants to see black and red bikes, how would I be able to find which items are selected in the ModelMultipleChoiceField?

Comment: But that doesn't have anything to do with the many to many field. The relationship between User and Colour is a straight foreign key and does not go via Bike. You would just do `request.user.colors_set.all()`.

Comment: Ah, got it.  Thank you.  I marked yours as the answer.